# 400 : Invalid entry ID/URI error in Batch Operation

Tags: java, xml, google-contacts-api

I'm currently implementing the Contact Application using Google Contact API in Java .
And I have completed individual addition ,deletion and updation of contacts. 
Now I'm implementing batch operation on contacts.

I have created the XML file that need to be send as the body of the request for batch operation. Following is the body of the request which i have created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch"
    xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008"
    xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
    <entry gd:etag="*">
        <batch:id>delete</batch:id>
        <batch:operation type="delete"/>
        <id>https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/27f2a9228b8abcde</id>
    </entry>
    <entry gd:etag="*">
        <batch:id>update</batch:id>
        <batch:operation type="update"/>
        <id>www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/1f3f94f58cabcde</id>
        <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#contact"/>
        <gd:name>
            <gd:givenName>abc</gd:givenName>
        </gd:name>
        <content type="text">Notes</content>
        <gd:email address="klm@gmail.com" primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"/>
        <link href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/1f3f94f58c4abcde" rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*"/>
        <link href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/1f3f94f58c4abcde" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
        <link href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/1f3f94f58cabcde" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"/>
        <gd:phoneNumber primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other">912377xxxx</gd:phoneNumber>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <batch:id>create</batch:id>
        <batch:operation type="insert"/>
        <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2008#contact"/>
        <gd:name>
            <gd:givenName>xyz</gd:givenName>
        </gd:name>
        <gd:email address="xyz@gmail.com" primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"/>
        <gd:phoneNumber primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work">9876xxxxxx</gd:phoneNumber>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

When I send the above XML as the body of the **POST** request to the URI

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch
```

in `OAuth Playground` and `Postman` I'm getting valid response.

But when I send the above XML as the body of the request in my Java code I'm getting the below XML as the response and 200 as the response code.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'
    xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>
    <id>https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/testcontact105%40gmail.com/base/batch/1529948621576</id>
    <entry>
        <id>https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/27f2a9228b829055</id>
        <updated>2018-06-25T17:43:41.576Z</updated>
        <title>Error</title>
        <content>Invalid entry Id/Uri</content>
        <batch:id>delete</batch:id>
        <batch:status code='400' reason='Invalid entry Id/Uri'/>
        <batch:operation type='delete'/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/1f3f94f58c410013</id>
        <updated>2018-06-25T17:43:41.577Z</updated>
        <title>Error</title>
        <content>Invalid entry Id/Uri</content>
        <batch:id>update</batch:id>
        <batch:status code='400' reason='Invalid entry Id/Uri'/>
        <batch:operation type='update'/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/5054af850dde6483</id>
        <updated>2018-06-25T17:43:41.577Z</updated>
    <gd:name>    <gd:givenName>xyz</gd:givenName>     </gd:name>
    <batch:id>create</batch:id>
    <batch:status code='201' reason='Created'/>
    <batch:operation type='insert'/>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home' address='xyz@gmail.com' primary='true'/>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work' uri='tel:+91-98679-99999' primary='true'>9867xxxxxx</gd:phoneNumber>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Below is my Java Code

```
String getUrl = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch?oauth_token=" + accessToken;
URL url = new URL(getUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");
con.setRequestProperty("Gdata-version","3.0");      
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(responseXML.length()));
//responseXML is body of the request
con.getOutputStream().write(responseXML.getBytes("UTF8"));
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode() + ":" + con.getResponseMessage());
```

Batch insert operation is working perfectly. But Update and delete operations are not working properly.

I have tried to replace base by full in uri with the suggestion found in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756279

But I'm getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do believe you don't need to set the `Content-Length` header

Comment: @JennaSloan Yeah. `Content-Length` header is not necessary. But that's not the reason for this `Invalid entry Id/Uri` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the request XML and finally made my code to work.

I replaced every `'default'` in the XML with `userEmail` (My Mail ID).

I still don't know why the code produce error with `'default'`. I know

`The special userEmail value default can be used to refer to the authenticated user`

But Individual add , delete and update operations are worked perfectly with `default` value and batch operations are failed to work with default value.